# Laravel 4 public files not updating on edit

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant

I am using Laravel together with a Vagrant setup, on my developer box.

I have run into an odd problem though. When I edit a css or js files, in my Laravel public folder, the changes does not apply.

If I SSH to the Vagrant box, and edit the file, I can see my changes are there in the file, but its like Laravel caches the old ones, and do not update to the new file.

If I then write the file again, that I just opened for edit, in my SSH terminal, the file will update on reload.

How come that when I edit it through my editor, and save it, Laravel do not seem to recognize the change, until it is opened and saved again through SSH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this kind of behaviour when the clocks on your PC and the server are out of sync. So the PC might be setting the timestamp into the past, therefore the cache won't update the changes.

(Not sure if you're saying you *are* using a cache in Laravel or not, if not then this probably won't be the cause).

Comment: Ok, it turned out to be a combination of things. One of them being the clock of the PC and the virtual PC was out of sync. But also another issue was the user, running the nginx server, was not correct. I had just givven all users full read and write access, but this did not work. I instead changed the nginx user, to be the vagrant user, and then it all worked.

Comment: Ok glad I was some help!

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else has this issue when using Nginx and Vagrant, I found this article (http://jeremyfelt.com/code/2013/01/08/clear-nginx-cache-in-vagrant/) that worked for me. To summarize (in case the URL above goes dead) update your nginx.conf file so the 'sendfile' setting is set to off.